# How to get Email title using MAPI on Windows Mobile?

Tags: c#, email, windows-mobile, dllimport, mapi

I want to get email title in PockerOutlook in Windows Mobile, but currently Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook has the ability to:

- Enumerate messaging accounts.
- Send Email
- Send SMS
- Intercept SMS

So I want to DLLImport MAPI.DLL to get its functions in order to get the title of email.

I find [this reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/hegenderfer/archive/2009/04/28/intercepting-mail-using-imapiadvisesink.aspx) written in C++. It seems to be difficult to convert to C# version due to different data type. Should I create a dll file by myself written in C++ and DLLImport to C# app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a C# person, but [MAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb446118.aspx) is a COM based system.  So you don't want to import the MAPI dll, you want to use whatever C# system has for warpping COM interfaces ([COM Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446497.aspx)).

You enumlate the messaing stores with [ICEMAPISession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb159727.aspx) then you enumlate the folders in each store (or go directly to known folders like the "inbox") with [IMsgStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb159712.aspx).  Then you can emulate the messages in the folder with [IMAPIFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb159903.aspx).

Once you get the email message entry ([IMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb446198.aspx)) you ask for the [PR_SUBJECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb415503.aspx) property.

You have to get used to the COM Interop in C# and the somewhat confusing MAPI interface.